# Inductor calculations for buck converter

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, kicad

I found this application report [Basic Calculation of a Buck Converter's Power Stage](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva477b/slva477b.pdf?ts=1599815126675&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Q :

- Can I use this report for products of other companies like ROHM, ALpha and Omega Semi...
- For the selection of the inductor, did (Lpeak=Iout+Delta_Iout/2 = 4.4A ) represent the current rating of the inductor. what margin is required to choose the saturation current.

This is the circuit that I designed.  Can anyone make a revision to it.
I am working with AOZ1284 [Datasheet](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1284PI.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Indicate what formula you used to calculate the inductor. Nobody wants to plough through the TI document trying to 2nd guess the formula you used to arrive at 4.7 uH.

Comment: @Andyaka From the general rule V = L × dl/dt. For an input voltage of 12V, the duty cycle will be:
D = Vo/Vi = 5/12 = 0.416
Where Vo is the output voltage and Vi is the input voltage.
Vl = Vi - Vo = 7V when the switch is on;
Vl = - Vo = -5V when the switch is off.
Selecting a 1.24A ripple current (31%), the required inductance is: L = Vl.dt/di = (7 × 0.416/500K Hz)/1.24
L = 4.7µH

Comment: @Andyaka the formula L=Vo/(Fsw*Delata_I)*(1-Vo/Vin) gives the same result

Comment: So, do you need to ask about the report if you are happy with those formula? You are wanting to know about the TI report so, if you already have the formula why ask?

Comment: @Andyaka I am newbie so be easy on me. I would like to know if I could use report or application note from one company with another companies. I sow some instruction for selecting output capacitor in Ti's documentation. Can you help me with this   For the selection of the inductor, did (Lpeak=Iout+Delta_Iout/2 = 4.4A ) represent the current rating of the inductor. what margin is required to choose the saturation current.

Comment: What you are asking for is too much. For me to say yes, it would mean me vetting the whole TI document and then using my crystal-ball-reading skills to anticipate what sort of future circuits you may or may not consider and whether these are covered in the TI document. Listen to me when I say this - YOU be reasonable and embed the formulas that you think you might want to rely on (from the TI document) into your question and make it "easy" on anyone attempting to answer this currently unanswerable question. This is a question and answer site - stick to the format and don't be excessive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112909/discussion-between-walid24-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I rarely do chat through being too busy.